# send_mail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'recipient_list'

Tags: python, django, gmail

Why i am receiving this error? **send_mail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'recipient_list'** did i miss something?

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template import Context, loader


def contact(request):

     Email = request.POST['Email']
     ....


     email_template = loader.get_template('accounts/print.html')
     send_mail(email_template, [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER], Email, fail_silently=False)
```

Update

```
email_template = loader.get_template('accounts/print.html')

send_mail('Your Enrollment: ', email_template, [Email], [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER], fail_silently=False)
```

this is the error i receive **'Template' object has no attribute 'splitlines'**

Answer (score 1):

I think `send_mail` is expecting the positional argument `recipients_list` to be of the type `list`:

```
send_mail(email_template, [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER], Email, fail_silently=False)
```

needs to be

```
send_mail(email_template, [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER], [Email], Email, fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: "to" argument must be a list or tuple

Comment: Right! currently, I think you are passing it a string - ```Email```. So make it ```[Email]``` or ```(Email, )```

Comment: `send_mail(email_template, [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER],  [Email], (Email), fail_silently=False)` i receive this error 'list' object has no attribute 'splitlines'

Comment: Review the order of the positional arguments and make sure they are correct, that could be causing the issue: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#send-mail

Comment: have you seen my update question? how do send my email template?